# How do I pause an XNA game?

Tags: xna, pausing

I'm trying to implement *pausing* by following [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195026%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx#Y539). The tutorial recommends essentially this as the implementation:

```
if (!paused) {
    Simulate(gameTime);
}
```

How does this work? What does `Simulate` mean here?

Comment: So I just had a look at the downloadable source code and it seems that Simulate is a method thats being called. 

Is there a way to code "continue game like normal" instead of this simulate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just a simple way to wrap your entire `Update` method in a conditional, without mixing the pausing logic with your game's updating logic.

So instead of:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(!paused)
    {
        // Lots and lots of code!
    }
}
```

You can have:

```
private void Simulate(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Lots and lots of code!
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(!paused)
    {
        Simulate(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Of course, if you would prefer to express it as "continue the game like normal", you could also do this:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(paused)
        return;

    // Lots and lots of code!
}
```

These all do the same thing. Which method you choose to do it is simply a matter of taste. Basically what the tutorial is telling you is:

- Determine if your game should be paused and store that in a variable (ie: `bool paused`)
- If it is paused, *skip over* the code that is responsible for updating your game's state (essentially freezing it in time, ie: "pausing" it.)

Comment: "By lots of code!" do you mean other code thats in the update method or pausing code?

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean now, but because my game has different gamestates and various methods to update the game, then I think the example in the tutorial I was using is a bit basic perhaps?

To be honest I only want a simple method that evaluates whether a button is pressed to allow the game to puse so I would appreciate it if someone could write me one so I know what to do in future :)

Comment: Just dont skip the code that checks for leaving paused state...

Comment: @Tom If you are using `GameComponent`s, you want to set `GameComponent.Enabled = false` on each of them when your game pauses. You may also get away with simply skipping the call to `base.Update()`, which is what calls `Update` on each `GameComponent`. Having a "Pause Button" is already described in the tutorial you linked.

Comment: Ok, so I just did it all over again but the games doesnt actually pause :S. I havent got any gamecomponents so I couldnt do your first suggestion so I tried calling the base.Update within the if(!paused) but its not working... :(

Comment: @Tom: (As I say at the end of my answer) you need to find the code that is updating/modifying/advancing your game's state and wrap it in an `if(!paused)` block. In other words: "*if not paused, run lots-and-lots-of-code*".

Comment: @Tom If you are having trouble understanding the flow of your code, try setting a break-point (for example: at the start of your `Update` method), and stepping through it in the debugger. If you have never done this before - experiment with "step into" and "step over" buttons. Note that by default you cannot step into the framework code - you can only step into your own code. You will also be able to mouse-over variables and inspect their values.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I've fixed it now.. I was calling my snakes update code twice which is why it didnt work. Now I've only got it once in the !pause method which works perfectly. The "lots and lots of code" only needed to be one line which was the snake moving :)

Answer (score 3):

As Andrew mentioned, you can simply add a flag in the `Update` loop to check the game's state. However, if your game is a bit more complex, you might want to take a look at the [Game State Management code sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management), that demonstrates multiple screens, transitions and a pause menu.

Comment: My game has three gamestates and different methods for updating the game. I'm guessing from "lots of code" Andrew means all the code that the game runs to update the game?

Comment: Yup, that's what I understand it to be. It's the non-pause related part of the game (i.e. everything else :) )

Comment: +1 I was going to link this too. The idea is that components belong to a screen, and it's the screen's responsibility to update those objects. Pausing just means pulling up a screen that blocks all those behind it from being updated. There is no need to fiddle with each component's individual on/off state, and there's no danger of locking yourself out if you know your pause screen has a resume button.

Comment: I just entered some update code (My snake character which moves on its own) into the "if(!paused)" method which is supposed just allow the game to continue as long as the pause button isnt pressed - When I played the game it turned out that the pause button altered the speed of the snake and didnt actually pause it which has confused me. Has anyone gopt any suggestions?

Comment: @Tom: Are you in fact toggling pause on and off constantly?