# How do I pause and resume a game in ActionScript 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript, pausing

I'm making a game where the player must avoid random falling objects. I dont know how to implement pausing. I've been stuck on this for 2 days!

I tried using `gotoAndPlay` and such, but the objects continue to run in the background. When I resume the game, they're still falling and it seems like the frame resets and loads new random falling objects.

(Simple English would be appreciated; English isn't my mother tongue.)

Comment: I don't know ES2 specifically, but [generally](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11608/how-do-i-pause-an-xna-game) pausing is implemented with an `if`-statement in your game loop, which replaces the usual game updates as long as the game is paused. (That XNA solution should be a good starting point.)

Comment: Lol They're fixing my questions, it's the actionscript 2 by the way..

Answer (score -2):

I hope this example will helpful for you here i have two frames MainIntro and 
Gameplay if i cick the button of play then it moves to the next frame of 
 GamePlay and then invoke the functions. Here i used gotoAndStop()..

```
package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;


import Globe;


public class MainIntro 
{


    public function MainIntro(Mc:MovieClip) 
    {
        Globe.self.realstage = Mc;

        Mc.intro_mc.play_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GameStart);
        Mc.intro_mc.play_mc.buttonMode = true;
        Mc.intro_mc.ins_btn.buttonMode = true;

    }

    public function GameStart(e:MouseEvent):void
    {

Globe.self.realstage.intro_mc.play_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
GameStart);
        Globe.self.realstage.gotoAndStop(2);
        var gameply:GamePlay = new GamePlay();
    }

}       

  }
```

Comment: This in no way answers the question asked.

Comment: To avoid more downvotes in the future I suggest you read the help page on providing high quality answers: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer